# How to exclude subdomain directory from main website

Tags: apache, dns, apache2, subdomain, cloudflare

I've setup a VPS with apache2.
I am using cloudflare for DNS management.
Now, I have my websites's files in "var/www/website" folder. Inside that, there is another folder for forum. like "var/www/website/forum" inside which there are all forum related files.

Now, suppose I have www.website.com pointing to "var/www/website"
and I also have a subdomain forum.website.com pointing to "var/www/website/forum".

What I want to do is make the files inside "var/www/website/forum" accessible via subdomain only. I don't want users to access forum via www.website.com/forum, but I want them to access it only via "forum.website.com"

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set up what's called a virtual host.  You would put your forum at /var/www/forum and website at /var/www/website.

inside /etc/apache2/sites-available, you'll need to add an additional configuration file for that site called forum.website.com.conf.

You'll then need to create a symbolic link to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled for that file so that apache sees it.  From there, you reboot the server and are good to go.

Here's some documentation:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

This may be a bit different depending on the flavor of linux, but should be about the same.  Control panels like Cpanel, Plesk and WebMan can make this process a bit easier by abstracting the configuration to a web control panel.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, drj. I am already using apache Vhosts for website and forum. So, what I did was, I moved the forum directory out of the website's root and then pointed the forum's vHost there.